# Firebase/Hugo build from Github succeeds, but index error occurs on website

Tags: git, firebase, google-cloud-platform, hugo, google-cloud-build

Building a Firebase/Hugo static website that updates when Github repo changes.

I am using the standard theme from the Quickstart guide: https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/

The webpage runs fine locally.

```
hugo server -D
```

The webpage runs fine when I deploy build to Firebase.

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

The webpage does not run fine when I trigger the build from Github repo, despite Google Cloud Build saying it successfully.

- Commit and push changes to Github repo
- Triggers a Google Cloud Build based on the cloudbuild.yaml in Github
- Both build steps (Hugo and Firebase) are successful

The result of visiting the URL is the following message:

```
Page Not Found

This file does not exist and there was no index.html found in the current directory or 404.html in the root directory.

Why am I seeing this?

You may have deployed the wrong directory for your application. Check your firebase.json and make sure the public directory is pointing to a directory that contains an index.html file.

You can also add a 404.html in the root of your site to replace this page with a custom error page.
```

I've tried changing the "baseURL" in config.toml to the custom domain, the firebase domain, and the Github repo URL. Nothing.

[Link to the Github repo here.](https://github.com/syphon5/syphon5com)

4/16 Update: It works if I **do not** include *public* folder in the .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

Did you complete the [CI Setup](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-firebase/)?

Comment: Yup. I also did this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/blob/master/firebase/README.md